# MySQL - math queries

Tags: sql, database, mysql

How can we find percentile, skewness and kurtosis in MySQL?
Is there any formula?
I want to find the above three for a large number of data records.

Thank you,
J

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jillika,

Here is a simple query for skewness and excess kurtosis for data in the [sales] table from Microsoft's "pubs" sample database:

```
select sum((qty-mean)*square(qty-mean)
       /(N*sigma*square(sigma))) as skew,
       sum(square(square(qty-mean))
       /(N*square(square(sigma))))-3 as ExcessKurtosis
from pubs..sales,
(
  select
    avg(qty) as mean,
    stdev(qty) as sigma,
    count(qty) as N
  from pubs..sales
) S
```

(This and some other statistics queries are posted here: http://users.drew.edu/skass/sql/, and a query for Spearman's rho is here: http://stevekass.com/2008/03/29/spearmans-rho-for-sql-server/).

Also look at what Dejan Sarka has written on the topic [here](http://blogs.solidq.com/dsarka/Post.aspx?ID=82&title=Skewness%20and%20Kurtosis%20Part%203%20%E2%80%93%20Another%20T-SQL%20Solution).

Answer (score 1):

I'd have to look up in the reference, but just in case you don't find the mathematical function you need, have a look at [stored procedures](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-routines.html). With this, you can define your own algorithms, if they're not present already.

Here's a nice [tutorial](http://www.brainbell.com/tutorials/MySQL/Using_Stored_Procedures.htm), that you may want look into.